# Basler camera with Pylon on Ubuntu - Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem to 'video'

Tags: ubuntu, camera

I'm using a Basler camera with Pylon on Ubuntu 18.04.  Only after a startup or reboot, I get the warnings listed below.  This occurs with any program that connects to a Basler camera.  The odd thing is everything still works (grabbing frames, etc.).  The warning occurs the same if I use Pylon with C++ or if I use the new Python wrapper PyPylon.

Here is the warning, for example if I compile and run the Grab.cpp sample that ships with Pylon here is the output:

```
$ ./Grab 
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_fglib_init_lock to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_fglib_mssync_GenTLSession_lock to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso-hw-me6-init to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_0_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_1_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_2_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_3_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_4_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_5_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_6_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_7_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_8_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_9_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_10_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_11_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_12_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_13_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_14_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_15_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_16_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_17_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_18_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_19_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_20_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_21_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_22_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_23_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_24_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_25_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_26_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_27_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_28_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_29_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_30_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Warning: Cannot change group of /dev/shm/sem.siso_mE_31_Bar_0_Page_4 to 'video'.
Using device a2A1920-51gcBAS
SizeX: 1912
SizeY: 1080
Gray value of first pixel: 108

SizeX: 1912
SizeY: 1080
Gray value of first pixel: 62

SizeX: 1912
SizeY: 1080
Gray value of first pixel: 104

SizeX: 1912
SizeY: 1080
Gray value of first pixel: 73

SizeX: 1912
SizeY: 1080
Gray value of first pixel: 90
.
.
.
```

To be honest I'm not familiar enough with Ubuntu/Linux to fully understand what these warnings mean.  Clearly it has something to do with group permissions, shared memory, and a video device in /dev, but I'm not sure any more specifically than that.

I should make it clear that if I do a reboot and run for example ./Grab as above, the warnings will occur as shown.  But then if I stop the program and restart it any number of times the warnings do not happen.  They only happen again after another reboot.

Can anybody please explain what is going on here, is there a fix, and since the camera(s) still works fine is this warning something I should be concerned about?

Comment: I am seeing the same. Adding the local user to the group "video" lets the warnings disappear. I am quite confident, that the warnings are not indicating a real problem, though. Grabbing works fine and also those file exist and are readable and writable by the local user.